# image as the background without css

Tags: html, css

I have a div that should always be in the center of the browser. now there's an image that will always be in the middle of the browser. but problem is that a div is 960px wide and but the picture is 1263px. how do I solve the problem? what I still need is dead as soon as the browser window smaller, should come scrollbars only at 960px. I know that I could theoretically solve anything, if I image Tell css as a background-image integrate the. but that does not work, unfortunately, because I really need the img tag

```
    #header-bottom {
    height: 1245px;
    background: red;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.header-bottom-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 545px;
}  



 <div id="header-bottom">
             <div class="header-bottom-wrapper">
                 <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1263x545/000/fff">
                </div>
            </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UcLnD/

Comment: Why do you REALLY need the image tag?

Comment: because I use a jqueryslider and needs the img tag

Comment: This question description is brought to you by Google translate - almost making perfect sense after translation

Comment: You could try `.header-bottom-wrapper { overflow: hidden }` to clip the image.

Comment: sorry, but my english is very bad..

Comment: Why is a CSS solution not allowed?

Comment: when i try overflow: hidden, i can't see the whole image. but when the browsersize is bigger than 960px, i want to see the whole image.

Comment: @Paulie_D a CSS solution is allowed, but i need the img tag for the jquery slider

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
#header-bottom {
    height: 1245px;
    background: red;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.header-bottom-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 545px;
}

.header-bottom-wrapper img {
    margin-left: -152px;
}
```

Comment: ok, why margin-left: -152px? with this solution, i can't see the whole image

Comment: To see the whole image, remove the overflow: hidden; for the #header-bottom.
If the container is more small that the image, you must rest the difference between the image-container/2, why /2? because is the only way to be sure that you have the same difference to the left and the right

Comment: ok, thank you. but when i remove the overflow: hidden, i get scrollbars :(

Comment: Wait, if the image are bigger than the container, how do you wanna see the entire image?

`.header-bottom-wrapper img {
    width: 960px;
}`

Comment: i don't understand it, sorry.

Comment: With this line, you can see the entire image

.header-bottom-wrapper img { width: 960px; }

Answer (score 0):

you can use negative margin to virtually reduce space needed by image.

```
<div class="clipimg">
<img src="imagetoowide-1000px" />
</div>
```

```
.clipimg {
width:500px;
text-align:center;
}
clipimg img {
margin:0 -50%;
}
```

Tune negative margin for both right/left and text-align.

Example here centers image and clips sides

examples : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/hjyEv/

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you mean by not using Css for your fix. But does the image need to stay the same size? If you want the image to resize based upon browersize add this to your Css:

`.header-bottom-wrapper img {width:100%;}`

```
#header-bottom {
    height: 1245px;
    background: red;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.header-bottom-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 545px;
}  

.header-bottom-wrapper img {width:100%;}


 <div id="header-bottom">
             <div class="header-bottom-wrapper">
                 <img src="http://dummyimage.com/1263x545/000/fff">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: the image should have the same size